# A thread or listener which will check some data in database ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, listener

I would like to create a thread or listener (I'm pretty new in threading, that's why I'm asking here) which will check every one day if Return_Date is or isn't null and if it is null then it will send an email to me and person who rent items that he/she hasn't returned them yet. I just need a function which will create this thread/listener, everything else like sending emails I'll do by myself.

This is my ItemRent class:

```
public class ItemRent
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemRentID { get; set; }
    (...)
    public DateTime Rent_Date { get; set; }

    public string Time { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> Plan_Return_Date { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> Return_Date { get; set; }
}
```

This is my ending function which adds data to database:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("SaveRent")]
    public ActionResult SaveRentConfirmed(int ID)
    {
        var temp = from x in db.ItemRentLists
                   where x.ItemRentID == ID
                   select x;
        SavingRent(temp);
        ItemRent itemRent = db.ItemRents.Find(ID);
        itemRent.Confirmed = true;
        db.Entry(itemRent).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

// HERE I WOULD LIKE TO START A THREAD/LISTENER AND CONTINUE E.G. ADDING NEW RENTS OR DO ANYTHING ELSE IN MEANTIME

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = ID });
    }
```

What exactly do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

This will create a thread to run the code in private void MyVoidMethod()

```
myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyVoidMethod));
myThread.IsBackground = true;
myThread.Start();
```

If you need to pass in parameters, use ParameterizedThreadStart instead.

There are lots of good tutorials on this topic...

Comment: Then if in MyVoidMethod ReturnDate will not be null and then I would like to stop this thread how can I do that?

Comment: `private void MyVoidMethod(int ID)
        {
            var ItemRent = db.ItemRents.Find(ID);
            if (ItemRent.Return_Date == null)
            {
                if (ItemRent.Plan_Return_Date < DateTime.Today)
                {
                    //SendEmail();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //stop thread
            }
        }`

Comment: You can eliminate the else statement altogether - then if Return_Date is null, you will reach the end of the method.  The thread will stop whenever the method is done, and should be garbage collected.

Comment: I would like this thread to check every one day if ReturnDate is null. If it is null then there is another if and if it is true then I would like the method SendEmail() to be done. This should be repeated till the ReturnDate is not null (if ReturnDate is not null then the Thread should stop)

Comment: Well, I have no idea how you are structuring this application... You could probably use a Timer that fires every day, assuming that the application will never, ever be shut down, but I don't see that being the most reliable method.  I would personally put all of this code into a simple console application or something and use a Windows Scheduled Task to run it every morning.  Use a database to track who needs an email.  Then you don't have to worry about threading, or how to keep track of when it runs, or anything else.  There may be more to your application than what I know about, though...

Comment: Do you have any other ideas how I could solve that problem? console application is not a solution in this particular situation :/

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you make your entire application into a console application, just that maybe a web site should not be handling batch processing like this... web apps are stateless and are not designed to run long-running tasks for weeks at a time.  Even if you get it to work, it will chew up tons of memory and not scale well.  Keep your existing web app to do the things it was meant for, and move all of your "once a day stuff" to a different project that uses a different architecture.  Based on what I know, that's the best advice I can give you...

Comment: What about another table in database which will contain only those records which have ReturnDate == null and one thread which will check every day if PlanReturnDate < Today and if true then sending email, if false then check tommorow? If someone return their items then the record from this table will be removed.

Comment: First you don't need another table for ReturnDate == null - just make your query something like "select * from MyTable where ReturnDate is null" and you will get back only the null records.  Second, using a single thread to do that is fine, but how will you do that with ASP.Net?  That code only runs when you get a request from a web page and then the thread gets recycled.  Will you leave all the threads open forever, or check if a thread already exists?  ASP.Net doesn't seem like the way to do this, which is why I am suggesting a second project.  Most solutions have many projects - it's ok...

Comment: Yes I could select it from one table but what if I have 10.000 records in this table? Isn't it too big to check every day which records have ReturnDate == null? If it isn't a problem then yeah I won't create a second table. I will start this thread on every app start and it will work infinitive.

Comment: 10,000 records is fine.  If you have performance issues, then create an index on the ReturnDate column of the table so that all of the ReturnDate == null records are grouped together.  Then the database server doesn't have to search the entire table - it can jump straight to the null ones and grab them in a few milliseconds.  Search "create index" if you need help doing that.